# Keep part of .gitignore under version control but another part out

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` where I expect that certain parts should be shared across the project but other parts should be individual-specific. How can I achieve this or a similar effect?

My initial thought was to split the `.gitignore` into two parts, a project-shared and an individual-specific part, where the project-shared part is checked in but the individual-specific part is not. Searching on Google and StackOverflow suggests that there does not exist a splitting/including-other-file mechanism.

Does anyone have a good alternative? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Global (cross-repository) .gitignore settings**

You can setup a global .gitignore file valid for all Git repositories via the *core.excludesfile* setting. The setup of this setting is demonstrated in the following code snippet.

- Create a ~/.gitignore in your user directory
  cd ~/
  touch .gitignore

-- Exclude bin and .metadata directories

```
echo "bin" >> .gitignore
echo ".metadata" >> .gitignore
echo "*~" >> .gitignore
echo "target/" >> .gitignore
# for Mac
echo ".DS_Store" >> .gitignore
echo "._*" >> .gitignore
```

-- Configure Git to use this file as global .gitignore

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

The global .gitignore file is only locally available.

**Local per-repository ignore rules**

You can also create local per-repository rules by editing the .git/info/exclude file in your repository. These rules are not committed with the repository so they are not shared with others.

This allows you to exclude, for example, locally generated files

Comment: This also fixes the "everyone on the team uses a different editor" issue! Thanks!